# passing data from one side of the page right to left?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Passing the data from a data box input into a static logger on the left so basically what you type on the right is outputted on the left in its own little box? I need some js php help?

```
<div class="div-left">
text logged input
</>

<div class="div-right">
text box input
</>
```

Comment: You would do this with javascript. You would need an event listener to fire a function when you key up. Select the text from `div-right` and update the `div-left` content.

Comment: You wouldn't really do this with PHP. You would with JavaScript.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: Make sense in what way? That you want to do it, or that you want to do it with PHP?

Comment: It seems so simple on paper but I want to write it in javascript, forget php so I need to add an event listener to the div-right so that div-left is updated?

Comment: Yep, that is what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach event listener to input and update the target element as you type.

For example:

```
var left = document.getElementById('left');
var p = document.querySelector('.box p');
left.addEventListener('input', function(){
  p.innerText = left.value;
})
```

[Example codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgQLMp)

Comment: This makes sense but its beyond my tech skills thanks for the info.

Comment: actually, this doesn't  make sense and doesn't work

Comment: Which part is doesn't make sense @DCR ? I thought OP wants to pass data one input to another and the example is working for that. I read it again and I think I misunderstood the issue, OP wants to pass data to box from input. Editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't type directly into a div.  You can type into an input tag and remove the border.  To get the text to change as you type use onkeyup as oppose to an event listener

```js
function myFunction(){
text = document.getElementById("input").value;
document.getElementById("div-right").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
//input {border:0;outline:0;}
//input:focus {outline:none!important;}
```

```html
<div id="div-left" style="width:40%;float:left;margin-left:50px">
<input id = "input" onkeyup="myFunction()"\>
</div>
<div id="div-right" style="float:right;margin-right:50px;width:40%">
text box input
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for the input. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with jQuery.

```js
$('textarea').click(function(){$(this).select();});

$('textarea').keyup(function(){
   $('div').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea style="float:left;">Please type here</textarea>
<div style="white-space:pre;float:left; margin-left:30px;"></div>
```

Comment: Great thanks for the info. this works i was creating a logger type system.